How to utilize GraphServiceClient for dependency injection in application based permissions
I have created a interface and implementation that manually gets a access token from Azure everytime its injected using the code below:
using ARMS_API.CloudStorage;
using Azure.Identity;
using Box.V2.Config;
using Box.V2.JWTAuth;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace ARMS_API.Azure
{
    public class AzureServices : IAzureServices
    {
        protected IConfiguration _configuration;        
        public AzureServices(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient()
        {

            string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var chainedTokenCredential = GetChainedTokenCredentials();
            return new GraphServiceClient(chainedTokenCredential, scopes);

        }

        private ChainedTokenCredential GetChainedTokenCredentials()
        {
            var tenantId = _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]!;
            var clientId = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]!;
            var clientSecret = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]!;

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            // https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
            var devClientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var chainedTokenCredential = new ChainedTokenCredential(devClientSecretCredential);

            return chainedTokenCredential;
        }
    }

}

However, I was hoping that I could just inject GraphServiceClient directly similar to delegated permissions which all you do is set your services in the program.cs and it rretrieves the token automatically when the user signs in. I was attempting to implement this for application based permissions using the following:
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes: new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" })
.AddDistributedTokenCaches();

However, there is nothing that allows me to implement .AddMicrosoftGraph() similar to delgated permissions which that tacks on to the EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(). Am I missing something here?

Try codes below:
In Program.cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.InMemory;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

TokenAcquirerFactory tokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance();
builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityApplicationOptions>(
          option => tokenAcquirerFactory.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(option))
        .AddMicrosoftGraph()
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Appsettings.json,
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "TenantId": "Tenant_Id",
  "ClientId": "Client_Id",
  "ClientCredentials": [
    {
      "SourceType": "ClientSecret",
      "ClientSecret": "Client_Secret_Value_here"
    }
  ]
},

And this is my controller
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var a = await _graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(r => r.Options.WithAppOnly());
    return View();
}

In my sample, it's .net 8 MVC and uses <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.18.1" />, I referred to this sample.

==========================================
Write a method to return GraphServiceClient and inject it into anywhere we require it  builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUtilService, UtilService>();.
 public class UtilService : IUtilService
 {
    public GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient() {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "clientId";
        var clientSecret = "clientSecret";
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        return graphClient;
    }
}


This is exactly what I am looking for and will test today. Just curious how does this vary from using ChainedTokenCredential? I was even confused what that was despite implementing it from an example I found.

Just tested. In program.cs those lines of code show the same error I was getting that: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMicrosoftGraph' and no accessible extension method 'AddMicrosoftGraph' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)CS1061

Also I am using Microsoft.Graph 5.52.0 and Microsoft.Identity.Web 2.18.1 if that matters. I think those are the latest versions.

In my test sample, I created a new MVC .net 8 application. Then all my codes above are the changes in the project. Just like you see, I only used one nuget package Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient and I didn't install Microsoft.Graph. COuld you pls create a new MVC project and test with my codes to see whether it worked or not? It shall be very fast.

Strangely enough restarting vscode fixed that error however now I get an exception using graph client : IDW10503: Cannot determine the cloud Instance. The provided authentication scheme was ''. Microsoft.Identity.Web inferred 'Bearer' as the authentication scheme. Available authentication schemes are 'Bearer'. See https://aka.ms/id-web/authSchemes. "

The AAD application I used is a multi-tenant application, and I obtained required information(client id and client secret and tenant id) and use it in appsettings.json, just like what you can see in my post. I'm afraid you had some other authentication related codes/configurations inside your application which caused your issue. Just like what I mentioned above, you might create a new MVC project and copy paste all I shared above to see whether it worked for you, then combining my codes into your project.

By the way, if you don't want to use delegated api permission, nor want to integate AAD user sign-in module, you might not need to have builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication into your application.

Adding that as builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd");
seems to disrupt my current Okta authentication setup using builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(); I am assuming this potentially isnt possible :(

I already showed you the sample from offcial document, if this doesn't meet your requirement, then you can create an interface and a class implementing it, then in the case, init the _graphServiceClient, then you can addSignleton<interface, service>, so that you can use it. This won't bring any conflict with your current project.

Well you mentioned for application permissions I may need to add builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication but then this conflicts with builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(); which I use for okta authentication to decode the jwt token my SPA sends. So thats where I am struggling then to add this. If I can figure that out then maybe this approach will work. Any thoughts on that? Thank you for your help.

I don't want that as it requires to add much more codes for reproducing the issue, you might just write a class method to  return _graphServiceClient, then inject this class into anywhere you want to use application permission authorization, which won't bring any conflicts.
